# Passing arguments into map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I am trying to use the built in `map()` function on an Array.from () that returns some elements using Puppeteer.

The below is the code:

```
let res = await page.evaluate(elementPath => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(elementPath), (cin, index) => {
    return {
      cs: `state is ${this.s}`, // returns state is undefined
      cinemaIndex: index,
      cinemaId: cin.getAttribute('data-id'),
      cinemaName: cin.getAttribute('data-name'),
      cinemaURL: cin.getAttribute('data-url'),
    };
  }, {
    s: 'NSW'
  });
}, `div[data-state=${cinemaState}] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`, cinemaState);
```

I am not able to assign `cs` with variable `s` or `cinemaState`.

Wondering if  you have solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to explain this. this is what has worked for me. I had to replace the arrow function to a traditional function

```
let res = await page.evaluate(elementPath => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(elementPath), function (cin, index) // changed from (cin, index) => 
{
    return {
      cs: `state is ${this.s}`, // returns state is undefined
      cinemaIndex: index,
      cinemaId: cin.getAttribute('data-id'),
      cinemaName: cin.getAttribute('data-name'),
      cinemaURL: cin.getAttribute('data-url'),
    };
  }, {
    s: 'NSW'
  });
}, `div[data-state=${cinemaState}] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`, cinemaState);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1,2,3,4].map(function(num, index,wholeArray){
    console.log(num,index,wholeArray,this.s);
},{s:"nsw"})
```

maps takes two argument `callback` and `thisArg` whatever u will pass at the second arg will be accessible bi `this`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `s` to the `cinemaState` property in your [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement using the following method:

```
cinemaState: this.s,
```

Additionally, [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) has a built-in [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, so you should call the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function from within [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to avoid an intermediate array:

```
Array.from(arrayLike, mapFn);     // good
Array.from(arrayLike).map(mapFn); // bad
```

Lastly, you may want to use quotes around `cinemaState` in your attribute selector within your template literal selector string:

```
[data-state="${cinemaState}"] // good
[data-state=${cinemaState}]   // bad
```

Your final code should look something like this:

```
let res = await page.evaluate(elementPath => {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(elementPath), (cin, index) => {
    return {
      cinemaState: this.s,
      cinemaIndex: index,
      cinemaId: cin.getAttribute('data-id'),
      cinemaName: cin.getAttribute('data-name'),
      cinemaURL: cin.getAttribute('data-url'),
    };
  }, {
    s: 'NSW'
  });
}, `div[data-state=${cinemaState}] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`, cinemaState);
```

Comment: This is only if you are using the lamda syntax on a single line

Comment: @grant-miller, 
Not sure I am missing something. I will update the original question with my current code.. Basically 
`cs: `state is ${this.s}`, // returns state is undefined`